# Select option not showing required field

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

When I am setting same name  in HTML 'select name' and set_rules name in form validation rules; it does not showing it is a required field.

My controller for validation as follows:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cate', 'category name','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_select_validate');

function select_validate($abcd)
        {
        // 'none' is the first option that is default "-------Choose City-------"
            if($abcd=="none"){
                $this->form_validation->set_message('select_validate', 'Please Select Your Category.');
            return false;
            } else{
            // User picked something.
            return true;
            }
        }
    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){

        $this->index();
    }
```

My HTML select form code as follows:

```
<select name="cate" >
    <option value="none" selected="selected">Select Catagory</option>
    <?php
        foreach ($catagory_all as $value) {
            if(!empty($project) && ($project->cat_id == $value->cat_id)){
                echo '<option value="' . $value->id . '" selected="">' . $value->catagory . '</option>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<option value="' . $value->cat_id . '">' . $value->catagory . '</option>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: `value="none"` contains a value (none).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified you coding... Please check with that.
View:

```
    <select name="cate" >
                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Catagory</option>
//Just specify value as empty. From that we can easily use required.
                                        <?php
                                            foreach ($catagory_all as $value) {
                                                if(!empty($project) && ($project->cat_id == $value->cat_id)){
                                                    echo '<option value="' . $value->id . '" selected="">' . $value->catagory . '</option>';
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    echo '<option value="' . $value->cat_id . '">' . $value->catagory . '</option>';
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
```

Controller:

No need of callback. If the selection value is empty, It will return required error! 
You can only specify following this,

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cate', 'category name','trim|required|xss_clean');
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `callback_select_validateselect_validate` it means you code looking for function `select_validateselect_validate` in your code

so You have to change your function name from

```
function select_validate($abcd)
```

TO

```
function select_validateselect_validate($abcd)
```

OR remove `select_validate` from your callback

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cate', 'category name','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_select_validate');
```